# Run server automatically when I call html page

Tags: python, flask

I have build application in python using flask. Everything I need to run the code manually to start my app, I need help to run the server automatically in backend when I call my local html file.(this is just for that local machine)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean "when I call my local html"? double click on it? or calling from browser?

Answer (score 1):

To run the Python-Flask Webapp, right-click on the Flask script ⇒ Run As ⇒ Python Run. The following message appears on the console:

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  The Flask built-in web server has been started, listening on TCP port 5000. The web app has also been started. It routes the URL '/' request to main()

From a web browser, issue URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (or http://localhost:5000/) to trigger the web app (localhost is the domain name for the local loopback IP address 127.0.0.1).

Comment: Yes, but I need it to start automatically when I just type http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in chrome